# Why can JPQLs modifying queries only return void or int?

Tags: spring, jpql

When i want to modify the database via JPQL i have to mark the query as `Transactional` and `Modiyfing`. If i do so, the return type of the method representing the query has to be either `void` or `int`(representing the number of edited rows i think). Why are only the two return types allowed? If i do a HTTP-PUT request and update the object with an own JPQL query, i would like to return the updated object again. Whats the best way to do it if the return type of the query has to be `void` or `int`? Do i have to do a seperate query/request again which selects the object after it was updated?

**EDIT:**

Thats how i call the query:

```
if (inactivityListDTO.getProjectIds().size() > 0) {
  projectRepository.updateProjectsIsArchivedByProjectIds(inactivityListDTO.getProjectIds(), inactivityListDTO.getIsArchived());
}
```

Thats the query:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Project project SET project.isArchived = :isArchived, 
       project.archivedDate = current_date " +
       "WHERE project.id IN :ids")
void updateProjectsIsArchivedByProjectIds(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids, @Param("isArchived") boolean isArchived);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it finally boils down to execute a standard `UPDATE` SQL in the DB , and the `UPDATE` in standard SQL only returns the number of records being updated and does not return a result set.

And yes , if you need get a record 's value after update , you have to query it again. Alternatively , you should consider using a JPA way to update a record , which first query the object , then update it by changing its state . Something like below *(Assume you are using spring `@Transactional` to manage the transactional boundary)*:

```java
@Transactional
public void changeEmployeeSalary(Integer employeeId , Integer salary){
    Employee employee = entityManager.find(Employee.class , employeeId);
    employee.setSalary(salary);
}
```

In this way , you do not need to query the record again after it is updated and you also do not need to manually write a UPDATE SQL.

Comment: The reason i dont do the usual JPA approach of updating is because i want to update multiple objects in a list. If i do the JPA approach above, i would have to iterate over the list and update every single object in there which results in N queries if N is the size of the list. That slowed down my application, because each query to the database has a ping of 5ms. So i decided to write my own query which updates all objects in the list in just one query. Theres probably a way to update multiple objects(rows) in just one query without writing an own query but i didnt find a way.

Comment: What i show is just an example to show the idea. In your case, you can use a query to get a list of object in one query such that you do not need to get it in N times.

Comment: Ye, in my case i can just do the one query to update all objects in the list and then do another query to get a list of the updated objects again. I was just wondering whether you knew a way to update multiple objects inside a list in one query without having to write an own query. I posted my code above, would it be possible to achieve the same thing without an own query?

Comment: To retrieve a list of project by its ID , you have to write the JPQL . It is not difficult to write which is just `select project from Project project where project.id in :ids` in your case. Or you can just use spring-data built in JPA repository which already provides a method call `findAllById` to get a list of entity by a lists of ID.